# Proving $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{a^n}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ax)^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a^k-1)}$

Tags: power-series, riemann-zeta, infinite-product, dirichlet-series

By trying to prove that Riemann's Zeta function is analytically expendable to the whole plane with one pole, I went aside and noticed this identity about formal power series (which are obviously everywhere convergent for complex $x$):
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{a^n}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ax)^n}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a^k-1)},\quad\quad\forall a\in\mathbb{R}:a>1.
$$
I checked it for the first several terms on my computer and it matches. Can you help me prove this identity?
In my proof I would plug in $a=4$ and $a=3$ to prove that the Zeta function has the domain it has, although my first example to check was $a=2$. My idea was to continue Ramanujan's idea of transforming Riemann's Zeta function into Dirichlet's Eta function to represent Zeta as a quotient of two Dirichlet series that converge everywhere, denominator would be the function in the identity, with $x=2^{-s}$. That's the idea, the proof is not finished, so I am aware that this idea will probably fail in this shape. I will have to work more on it.

Comment: When you say you “noticed” this identity, and your question asks us to prove the identity; how do you even know for sure it *is* an identity? Where did it come from? The work of another author?

Comment: @FShrike I checked first few coefficients on computer

Comment: For all real $p$, $p\gt1$, and yet you cite specific values of $p$ less than one. What also is the domain of $x$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I written the identity wrongly the first time, but when I try to correct it it is a race against other edits. Sorry, come back to the link in few minutes

Comment: I would use a symbol different from $p$ ($y$ perhaps) since in the context of analytic number theory, $p$ often stands for a prime.

Comment: This identity is a theorem of Euler that comes from the q-binomial theorem in the limit $n\to\infty$: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem. A proof can be found here: https://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/smsmedley/Vol-33-2/The%20q-binomial%20Theorem%20(Chan%20Heng%20Huat,%20Chan%20Song%20Heng%20and%20Shaun%20Cooper).pdf

Comment: @Jacob Thank you very much! Would you post it as an answer so I can mark it and close the question?

Comment: I wish I've actually written down this proof that Zeta has only one pole :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with OP’s request, I am posting my comment below.

The identity is a theorem of Euler’s that comes from the [$q$-binomial theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem) in the limit $n\to\infty$. A proof can be found [here](https://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/smsmedley/Vol-33-2/The%20q-binomial%20Theorem%20(Chan%20Heng%20Huat,%20Chan%20Song%20Heng%20and%20Shaun%20Cooper).pdf).

Comment: See my answer, no need of any theorem

Answer (score 4):

For $|a|>1$ let
$$f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+x a^{-n}) =\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_m x^m$$
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_m a^m x^m=f(ax)= (1+x a) f(x)=1+\sum_{m=1}^\infty (c_m+a c_{m-1})x^m$$
Equating the coefficients we find that $$c_0=1,\qquad  c_m a^m=c_m +a c_{m-1}$$ ie. $$c_m  = \frac{a}{a^m-1}c_{m-1} = \frac{a^m}{\prod_{k=1}^m (a^k-1)}$$